# Trying to Export Data from an unusal Access Database with Synonyms

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008, ssis, odbc

We use a product called SalesOutlook which is a type of CRM system. I need to export data from this using SSIS or some other program.

When you install the program, it creates a DSN on my system called SalesOutlookReports. It use the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb).

When I try to look at it using Crystal Reports I see a list of tables like:

```
SchemaAccount Contacts
SchemaAccount Profiles
SchemaNotes
```

And then under that is another folder called Synonyms and it contains

```
Account Contacts
Account Profiles
Notes
```

If I open the synonyms, I get my data, if I open the schema tables I get the meta data about the table.

My question is this. How can I easily import information from the tables I need into SQL Server for manipulation? How can I designate the synonyms instead of the "tables" so I can import the data? I cannot find a way to do it using the import/export wizard with SQL Server nor in SSIS. Perhaps I could use a linked server from SSMS?

Comment: what do you see when you open up the DSN from SSIS?

Comment: I'm able to create a connection manager by selecting "New Connection" and selecting ODBC. Connection Succeeds. I'm not sure what kind of Data Flow Source to use to open it.

Comment: However, when I try the Import/Export Wizard from the Management Studio, I chose the .Net Framework Provider for ODBC. I enter the DSN and Driver in exactly as is found in my Data Source Administrator. I select a SQL Database and enter my credentials. When I select "Copy Data From one or more tables or views" I only see a list of the first set of records such as "SchemaNotes".

Answer (score 0):

ODBC connection in SSIS Data Flow Task should do the trick.  Place a Data Flow task and then inside that you can select an ADO.NET data source.  You can connect to an ODBC connection using that datasource.  Select your MS Access database and voila you have a source.  You can add derived columns if you need to adjust the data type and finally connect it to an OLEDB destination, which would be SQL Server.